# DockLayoutPanel inside ScrollPanel in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, scroll, docklayoutpanel

I'm using GWT 2.4 and I'm having a problem with setting up scrollbars for my app working correctly. When I'm trying to zoom the page - no scrollbars are now displayed for the whole page.

Currently my app is composed of DockLayoutPanel and is displayed in the following way:

```
private DockLayoutPanel appContainer = new DockLayoutPanel(Style.Unit.PX);
(...)
appContainer.addNorth(bannerSimplePanel, 104);
appContainer.addWest(menuSimplePanel, 200);
appContainer.add(new ScrollPanel(contentSimplePanel));

RootLayoutPanel.get().add(appContainer);
```

I want to have scrollbar configured for whole page instead of only "main content" (contentSimplePanel) of the page. I've tried to add scrollbar to the last step:

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(new ScrollBar(appContainer));
```

but it didn't work. With ScrollBar added for whole appContainer only banner is displayed on my page and the rest is black.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Adding   DocklayoutPanel to a ScrollPanel won't work. The inner layout
panel's height and width will be zero.
```

Use

```
dockLPanel.getWidgetContainerElement(flowPanel).getStyle().setOverflowY(Overflow.AUTO);
```

Have a look on this

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/BnboxugPuJQ

Comment: And what is flowPanel in this case? Is it e.g. center part of dockLPanel? It won't make whole page scrollable.

Comment: What I am saying is add overflow auto to your child's instead of whole body.If childs are big in size then automatically body scrolls.

Comment: Yes, but this is what I've managed to do :) I was wondering about another solution.

Comment: Do You have any restrictions to use css like 
body{
width:150px;
height:150px;
overflow:scroll;
}   also ??      :) :)

Comment: No .we can give in that way also.

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple fix I guess.

```
ScrollPanel sp = new ScrollPanel();
sp.setSize( "100%", "100%" );

private DockLayoutPanel appContainer = new DockLayoutPanel( Style.Unit.PX );
appContainer.addNorth( bannerSimplePanel, 104 );
appContainer.addWest( menuSimplePanel, 200 );
appContainer.add( contentSimplePanel );

sp.add( appContainer );
RootLayoutPanel.get().add( sp );
```

Comment: With this solution only banner is displayed. The rest of the page is blank... 

I've also tried to add ScrollPanel to RootPanel: RootPanel.get().add(sp); but after that whole page is blank....

Comment: Another solution worked fine. Yours unfortunately is not working.